# Imageloader only loading images in list after listitem has gone off screen

Tags: android, image, url, adapter

I have a listView with an adapter loading images from URLs through a ImageLoader class.
The problem is, the images on the screen are not displayed/loaded until the list item has been scrolled off screen.

So basically, the listView is shown, but no images are loaded until you scroll down and scroll back up again. This aplies to all the items in the list, when displaying them the first time no images are loaded until you scroll back to them.

I have not written the ImageLoader class myself and Im having a hard time understanding exactly why the images don't load on the first displaying. Have tried alot of different things with the queue but nothing seems to help.

The ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    //the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    private File cacheDir;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.nopic;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url)){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
            if (progressBar != null){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }else{
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView, progressBar);

            if(progressBar != null){
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //ADDED
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {

        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, progressBar);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int requiredSize = 100;

            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<requiredSize || height_tmp/2<requiredSize)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i, ProgressBar p){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
            progressBar = p;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread(){
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    // PHOTOSLOADER: Thread
    //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                                                            photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();                                                       photosQueue.photosToLoad.remove(photoToLoad);
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        Object tag = photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                        if(tag != null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView, photoToLoad.progressBar);
                            Activity a = (Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();


    //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    // BITMAP DISPLAYER
    //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable{
        Bitmap      bitmap;
        ImageView   imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i, ProgressBar p){
            bitmap = b; 
            imageView = i; 
            progressBar = p;
        }
        public void run(){
            if(bitmap != null){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                if (progressBar != null){
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else{
                if (progressBar != null){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        //clear SD cache
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }
}
```

The Adapter:

```
public class Adapter_Agenda extends BaseAdapter {

    // DEBUG
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ViewHolder holder;
    private ArrayList<Agenda> agendas;
    UnixTimeToStringConverter unixConverter;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

    View vi;

    public Adapter_Agenda(Context context, ArrayList<Agenda> agendas) {

        this.agendas = agendas;
        unixConverter = new UnixTimeToStringConverter();
         imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return agendas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Agenda getItem(int position) {
        return agendas.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        vi = convertView;

        if(convertView  ==  null){

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_agenda, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.header       = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.item_list_header);
                    holder.image            = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.item_list_image);
            holder.time         = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.item_list_time);
            holder.description  = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.item_list_description);

            vi.setTag(holder);
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }

        holder.header.setText(agendas.get(position).getHeader());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(agendas.get(position).getImageURL(), activity, holder.image, null);
   holder.time.setText(unixConverter.getUnixDateFormated(agendas.get(position).getStartTime()));

        return vi;
    }

    //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    // VIEWHOLDER
    //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    public class ViewHolder{

        public TextView         time;
            public ImageView                image;
        public TextView         header;
        public TextView         description;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your adapter never sets the image? The ImageLoader class is never used?!

Comment: Im sorry, I pasted the wrong adapter. Edited it so it reflects how I am using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just put

```
holder.image.setTag(agendas.get(position).getImageURL());
```

before

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(agendas.get(position).getImageURL(), activity, holder.image, null);
```

Comment: It did not work for me @Jahanzaib . What might be other possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

The Image will be downloaded in a new Thread. So what you are doing is an async file download. 
The problem is that you "use" your image BEFORE it's actually downloaded. As a result no image can be shown.

What you have to do:

Create sth like a callback when a image has been downloaded. You can achive this by creating a interface which will be implemented by your adapter.

Whenever the interface method is been called you know, that an image has been downloaded and you can notify the adapter by calling "notifyDatasetChange()".

Comment: ok, but where in the ImageLoader class should I add the callback? I can't get it working properly..